# keep li active while using pagination in django templates?

Tags: jquery, html, css, django, pagination

I am java script to keep my li in ul active on sidebar-nav.But it gets deactivated everytime I switch to page 2 as I am using pagination:

my ul li code is here:-

```
<li>
<a href="#" class="dropmenu"> <i class="fa fa-newspaper-o fa-lg margin_right5"></i> <span>News Management</span>
</a>
<ul>
<li class=" "><a href="{% url 'cms:news-list' %}" class="submenu"><span class="">News List</span></a></li>
<li class=" "><a href="{% url 'cms:news-reported' %}" class="submenu"><span class="">Reported News</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

what  I tried:-

```
<li>
<a href="#" class="dropmenu"> <i class="fa fa-newspaper-o fa-lg margin_right5"></i> <span>News Management</span>
</a>
<ul>
<li class="{% if request.path =='/news/list'%} active {% endif%} "><a href="{% url 'cms:news-list' %}" class="submenu"><span class="">News List</span></a></li>
<li class=" "><a href="{% url 'cms:news-reported' %}" class="submenu"><span class="">Reported News</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

but it is not working in case of pagination.

Answer (score 0):

There is the dyanmic solution for this activeness of the menu. Suppose you are having more than 20 or 30 urls , you have to write down a 50 conditions there.So instead of that try this,

Give sidemenu class to every `<a>` tag and loop through all the sidemenu elements and match it with the current url,
now suppose if your url is `'/news-list'`  and the location path is `/app/new-list` it will give active class to this `<a>` element

```
$('.sidemenu').each(function(i, obj) {
        var current_url = location.href.split('/'); // split the current url to get the last part of the url
        var lastSegment = current_url.pop() || current_url.pop();  // handle potential trailing slash
        var getlast = lastSegment.split('?'); // split your get parameters to remove them
        var a = getlast[0]; # get the actual url by accessing the first element of array

        var get_sidebar_url = $(obj).attr('href').split('/'); 
        var lastSegment2 = get_sidebar_url.pop() || get_sidebar_url.pop();  // handle potential trailing slash
        var getlast2 = lastSegment2.split('?');
        var b = getlast2[0];

        # match that your last part of url is matching with your current url , if yes then give active class to li
        if (b.startsWith(a) || a.endsWith(b)) {
            $(obj).parent('li').addClass('active');
        }else{
            $(obj).parent('li').removeClass('active')
        }
    });
```

**EDIT** :
But if you need temporary solution here is the thing you need to change,

change {% request.path %} to

```
{% if request.resolver_match.url_name  == 'news-list(your_actual_urlname)' %}
  active
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I am using one java script function to make my sidebar active but in the case of pagination, it doesn't work like `news/list?page=2&page_size=10'.That is why I was using `request.path `

Comment: Yes, you can remove that request.path condition and can try this logic instead for dynamic solution.